# Find the inverse of $\frac{x}{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am to find the inverse of $\frac{x}{x+2}$ and the solution provided is $\frac{-2x}{x+1}$. I am struggling to isolate x on one side:

$y = \frac{x}{x+2}$

$\frac{x}{x+2} = y$ # just move the x to the left side

$x = y(x+2)$ # multiply both sides by x+2 to multiply out the denominator

$x = yx + 2y$ # not sure how to isolate x?

$x-yx=2y$ # try moving the other x component to the left side too

I'm not sure where to go next but it feels like I'm moving further away from the solution $\frac{-2x}{x+1}$. How can I arrive at this?

Comment: Try $x(1-y)=2y$ for the next step, also the solution is slightly wrong.

Comment: Take $x$ common on LHS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by $$x+2\neq 0$$ we get
$$x=yx+2y$$
$$x(1-y)=2y$$ so
$$x=\frac{2y}{1-y}$$ for $$y\neq 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Your last equation implies $x=\frac{2y}{1-y}$, which can also be derived from $1-y=\frac{2}{x+2}\implies\frac{y}{1-y}=\frac{x}{2}$. Whatever source claimed the inverse was a certain function of $x$, not $y$, probably thought about the fact that $x\mapsto\frac{x}{x+2}$ is a function whose inverse might as well be written as $x\mapsto f(x)$ (expression to be determined). However, in that case it should be $\frac{2x}{1-x}$ or, if they prefer, $\frac{-2x}{x\color{blue}{-}1}$, not $\frac{-2x}{x\color{red}{+}1}$, so there's an obvious typo there.

Answer (score 1):

mohamm With $$x(1-y)=2y$$ you get $$x=\frac {2y}{(1-y )}$$

In order to get to the inverse function you swap $ x$ and $y$ so $$f^{-1}(x)=\frac {2x}{1-x}$$ for $x\ne 1$